# Printing out matching lines between two .txt files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following piece of code:

```
def readline():
    with open("textfile1") as f:
        while True:
            content = f.readline().strip()
            if content in open('textfile2').read():
                ##Print the matching line of textfile2
            if not content: break

def main():
  readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I have two text files (textfile1 and textfile2) I want to read each line of textfile1 and if it exist in the text of textfile2 I want to print out the correspoding line. I can do it for textfile1 however for textfile2 I can't. How can I fill the commented out space or any alternative solutions?

The files are not ordered and not same in length either.

Sample from Textfile1:

```
'landroid
lang
ljava
v'
landroid
'
'ljava
view
i
string
util
content
widget
init
z'
```

Sample from Textfile2:

```
lang             |            41748
'landroid        |            40157
ljava            |            37227
v'               |            32920
'ljava           |            27315
string           |            23233
'                |            22624
landroid         |            22156
i                |            19970
content          |            13311
view             |            12144
util             |            11546
init             |            11121
widget           |            10604
graphics         |             8581
```

Comment: Why can't you? What's happening that is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Are your files ordered? Perhaps you could edit your question to include sample input from your two files and the sample output that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You read a line from textfile1, check to see if it is in textfile2, and *then* check to see if you've reached the end of textfile1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set, storing all the single words from `file1`, the check if the first word from each line in file2 is in the set:

```
with open("file1") as f, open("file2") as f2:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip,f))
    for line in f2:
        spl = line.split(None, 1)[0]
        if spl in st:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
lang             |            41748
'landroid        |            40157
ljava            |            37227
v'               |            32920
'ljava           |            27315
string           |            23233
'                |            22624
landroid         |            22156
i                |            19970
content          |            13311
view             |            12144
util             |            11546
init             |            11121
widget           |            10604
```

Obviously `spl` will be the word from file1 so you can use that if you want the matching word.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: No worries,  it will be a lot faster to check if a single word from each line is in the set than to check every word against every line  in file2

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for your two example files:

```
def readline():
    with open("textfile1") as f1, open("textfile2") as f2:
        d1_lines = {}
        for line in f1:
            d1_lines[line.strip()] = 0

        for line in f2:
            first = line.split("|")[0].strip()
            if first in d1_lines:
                print line.strip()

readline()
```

This would give you the following results:

```
lang             |            41748
'landroid        |            40157
ljava            |            37227
v'               |            32920
'ljava           |            27315
string           |            23233
'                |            22624
landroid         |            22156
i                |            19970
content          |            13311
view             |            12144
util             |            11546
init             |            11121
widget           |            10604
```

Testing using Python 2.7

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're iterating through the first file line by line, but you're reading the second one all into a single string, so that makes it difficult to get the specific line you were interested in. I assume each line in the first file is a potential subset of a line in the second file (short search queries in the first file with real content in the second), because if they were an exact match you could just print the line from the first file and you wouldn't have this issue.

The following opens both files with the `with..as` context manager, which ensures that both files are closed after the `with` block ends. Next, it goes through each line in the first file (the queries), strips off the whitespace, and adds it to a `list`. Once that's done, it will go through each line of the second file (the content), and go through each item in `queries`. If an item is found in the current line, it will print that line and go to the next one (instead of looking for more query matches in that line). I have also removed the unnecessary `readline()` function definition, putting the code into `main()`.

```
def main():
    with open("textfile1", 'r') as queries, open("textfile2", 'r') as content:
        queries = [line.strip() for line in queries]
        for line in content:
            for query in queries:
                if query in line: print(line)
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation